# E-Mail Form and form values - php

Tags: php, forms, email

I am trying to set a php mail form into my web site. First off all, I wanted to keep form values after submitting. if a user leave empty fields and  press submit button, that user will has to write same things again. I was managed to do it with the structure `<?php if (isset($_POST['Fields'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Fields']); }?>` However, I linked my form and  php mail codes each other, after submitting form values are disappearing. I haven't managed to do it yet. I don't have knowledge about php. There are the codes:

My Form (inside contact.php):

```html
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Name'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Name']); }?>" />
                
                <label for="Subject">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Subject'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Subject']); }?>"/>

                <label for="Phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Phone'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Phone']); }?>"/>
    
                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Email'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Email']); }?>"/>
                
                <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
                <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message">
                    <?php if (isset($_POST['Message'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Message']); }?>
                </textarea>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button" />
 </form>
```

My php file (mail.php):

```html
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
 echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$subject = $_POST['Subject'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['Email'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)||empty($message)) 
{
    header('Location: contact.php#jump'); // I'm gonna writing new stuff here
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    header('Location: contact.php#jump'); // I'm gonna writing new stuff here
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'updatedmail@mail.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Email from your web site";
$email_body = "You have received a new message via the web mail form \n".
    "Name: $name \n". 
    "E-Mail: $visitor_email \n".
    "Subject: $subject \n".
    "Message: $message \n".
    "Phone Number: $phone \n".

    
$to = "mymail@mymail.mail";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: contact.php#jump'); // I'm gonna writing new stuff here


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to include mail.php in contact.php. So in contact.php, on top write

```
<?php include("mail.php");?>
```

And if mail.php inside some folder include that folder name too like below:

```
<?php include("foldername/mail.php");?>
```

And remove mail.php from **action="mail.php"**

Let me know, if it's not working. :)

Comment: Actually, I am confised :) I removed the code action="mail.php" and I included mail.php in contact.php. As you said I put it on the top, it didn't work. I got an error "This web page has a redirect loop" :) I wrote including codes end of the contact.php and write action="" it is working but (if you take a look mail.php) link codes are not working at the moment. After submitting page should go to contact.php#jump but it is just refreshing now. Mail sending is working.

Comment: I found a new contact mail form and easily set it :) Thanks